# How do i take radio value checked in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I have this code so far, i try to take the value from radio button.I can take from v-model value but with radio i have some problems.For example if i have more radio buttons how i can take the checked one.

```
new Vue({
el:'#root',
data:{
  removelines: [
  {value:'a'},
  {value:'b'}
  ]

},

methods:{
 insert:function(){
     let vueIn = this; 

     axios.post('/vue', {removelines: vueIn.removelines.value}).then(
       function(response){
         vueIn.removelines = response.data.removelines.value;
       }
     ).catch(function(error){ console.log(error.message); });
   }
}

});
```

html code here:

```
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-warning active">
            <input  v-model="removelines" name="removelines" type="radio" class ="cheker" autocomplete="off" v-bind:value="a" checked>
            Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-warning">
            <input v-model="removelines" name="removelines" type="radio" class ="cheker" v-bind:value="b">
            No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this working sample, please.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    removelines: 'b'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
<div class="card-block">
  {{ removelines }}
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-warning active">
            <input  v-model="removelines" name="removelines" type="radio" class ="cheker" autocomplete="off" v-bind:value="'a'" checked>
            Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-warning">
            <input v-model="removelines" name="removelines" type="radio" class ="cheker" v-bind:value="'b'">
            No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AdrianKlark I don't know what your method is being used for and the endpoint you're using, and I cannot find the relationship between `insert` method and your question. Would you please update your question description?

Comment: thanks i modify it's seams bootstrap js have conflicts with other js

Comment: how can i contact you ?

Comment: just an addition: `v-bind:value="'a'"` can be shortened to `:value="'a'"`

Comment: or simpler `value="a"` works too